# npm ERR! code ENOSELF while installing react dependencies

Tags: reactjs, dom, npm, prop

when I try to install dependencies using 'npm install react react-dom prop-types --save-dev' to the react (in webstorm) it shows an error 'npm ERR! code ENOSELF'.

it did work correctly before so i tried 2 3 times creating new projects

npm install react react-dom prop-types --save-dev

npm install react react-dom prop-types --save-dev should install all the dependencies but it shows an error

Comment: Is the "name" attribute of your package.json set to "react" by any chance? Make sure that your "name" is not the same as any of your dependencies.

Comment: similar issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12884

Answer (score 1):

For this error,

1. make sure that the project name and package name should not be the same.
2. or just rename the package name property in my package.json in the branch...

Answer (score 0):

rename your project directory to something else.... 
then execute below command

```
npm audit fix
```

or

```
npm audit fix --force
```